# get html markup in xml json response - jquery ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have xml tag named **InnerHtml** which contains markup for html fields.

C#

```c#
Result = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><GETRESPONSE><FIELDS><FIELD><LABEL>FIRST NAME</LABEL><INNERHTML><div class='form-group'><label>First Name</label><input  id='txtFirstName' type='text' pattern='[0-9]{9,9}' class='large' /><label id='Error-FirstName' class='error'></label></div></INNERHTML></FIELD></FIELDS></GETRESPONSE>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(Result);
Result = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

I am making jquery ajax call and returning above response. Now i want to extract InnerHtml from above XML/JSON response and append to my existing html markup

Jquery Ajax Call

```javascript
success: function (data) {
var i;
var html;
var fieldLength = data.GETBILLERDETAILSRESPONSE.FIELDS.FIELD.length;
for (i = 0; i < fieldLength; i++) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.GETRESPONSE.FIELDS.FIELD[i].INNERHTML));
}
}
```

What I am getting in console is

```
{"div":{"@class":"form-group","label":["First Bane",{"@id":"Error-FirstName","@class":"error"}],"input":{"@id":"txtFirstName","@type":"text","@pattern":"[0-9]{9,9}","@class":"large"}}}
```

**But I want clear markup rather than above**

Comment: I think you can pass XML string instead of XMLDocument and at the client side you can use XML parsing to convert string to XML doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this placing the html inside `CDATA` like this

```
Result = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><GETRESPONSE><FIELDS><FIELD><LABEL>FIRST NAME</LABEL><INNERHTML><![CDATA[<div class='form-group'><label>First Name</label><input  id='txtFirstName' type='text' pattern='[0-9]{9,9}' class='large' /><label id='Error-FirstName' class='error'></label></div>]]></INNERHTML></FIELD></FIELDS></GETRESPONSE>";
```

Comment: Its giving output in js as `{"#cdata-section":"<div class='form-group'><label>CA Number</label><input  id='Ggcl-CANumber' type='text' pattern='[0-9]{9,9}' class='large' /><label id='Error-Ggcl-CANumber' class='error'></label></div>"}` How to get only `div` part in variable ?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(data.GETRESPONSE.FIELDS.FIELD[i].INNERHTML['#cdata-section']));

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe your javascript is cached?

Comment: Try clearing your cache and then run again. Make sure that your browser hasn't cached your js (maybe an alert as test?).

Comment: Solved. `JSON.stringify` not needed